# appengine: monitor dashboard from another app

Tags: java, google-app-engine, monitor

I'd like to monitor the dashboard of one GAE app (java) from one other (mostly I want to know the number of requests since the reset of the quota). How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an API to get quota details for the current request but not at the application level.

There is a current [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=655) for this functionality.  You can star it to show your interest.